# How to pass an argument that requires a parameter of type Food?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am writing a program that is based on the demonstration of inheritance. I am trying to write an exception so that the only parameter that can be passed into the Meat class which is linked to the class Wolf. In essence, I am trying to allow the only parameter that can be passed into the eating method to be a Food variable called Meat. Here is the code:

**Animal**

```
abstract public class Animal 
{

String name;
int age;  
String noise;

abstract public void makeNoise();

public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

abstract public Food eat(Food x) throws Exception;

}
```

**Food**

```
public class Food {

    //field that stores the name of the food
    public Food name; 

    //constructor that takes the name of the food as an argument
    public Food(Food name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Food getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Meat**

```
public class Meat extends Food 
{

    public Meat(Food name) 
    {
        super(name);
    }

    public Food getName() 
{
    return super.getName();
}
}
```

**Carnivore**

```
public class Wolf extends Carnivore
{

Wolf()   
{
    name = "Alex";
    age = 4;

}
    public void makeNoise()  
    {
        noise = "Woof!";
    }
    public String getNoise()  
    {
        return noise;
    }
    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }  
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public Food eat(Food x) throws Exception
    { 
        if (x instanceof Meat) {
                return x;
            } else {
               throw new Exception("Carnivores only eat meat!");
            }
    }    
}
```

**Wolf**

```
public class Wolf extends Carnivore
{

Wolf()   
{
    name = "Alex";
    age = 4;

}
    public void makeNoise()  
    {
        noise = "Woof!";
    }
    public String getNoise()  
    {
        return noise;
    }
    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }  
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public Food eat(Food x) throws Exception
    { 
        if (x instanceof Meat) {
                return x;
            } else {
               throw new Exception("Carnivores only eat meat!");
            }
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Wolf wolfExample = new Wolf();        
        System.out.println("************Wolf\"************");
        System.out.println("Name = " + wolfExample.getName());
        System.out.println("Age = " + wolfExample.getAge());
        wolfExample.makeNoise();
        System.out.println("Noise = " + wolfExample.getNoise());

        Meat meatExample = new Meat(//Food argument goes here?);
        System.out.println("************Wolf eating habits************");
        System.out.println("Wolves eat " + wolfExample.eat(meatExample.getName()));
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I cannot pass in anything as a food argument within the new Meat object that I create within my main method. And I mm getting the error of an unsupported exception when I try to call `System.out.println("Wolves eat " + wolfExample.eat(meatExample.getName()));`which I think may be because a Food variable has not been passed in. The desired outcome is that a Food variable such as Plants is passed in which throws an exception message. Any help on how to resolve this is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You should fix your messed up indentation.

Comment: just pass meatExample instead of meatExample.getName().

Comment: `Meat meatExample = new Meat(//Food argument goes here?)`still needs a Food argument to passed in which I am still unsure about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to modify your Animal and Food classes first and then with few other changes in your Main class, you may be able to achieve what you are trying to. Here are few suggested changes:

```
public class Food {

    //field that stores the name of the food
    public String name; 

    //constructor that takes the name of the food as an argument
    public Food(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Meat extends Food 
{
    public Meat(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();
    }
}


public class Main {
    public Main() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wolf wolfExample = new Wolf();        
          System.out.println("************Wolf\"************");
          System.out.println("Name = " + wolfExample.getName());
          System.out.println("Age = " + wolfExample.getAge());
          wolfExample.makeNoise();
          System.out.println("Noise = " + wolfExample.getNoise());

        try {            
            Meat meatExample = new Meat("Steak");
            //Food vegFood =  new Food("Spinach");
                    System.out.println("************Wolf eating habits************");
            wolfExample.eat(meatExample);
            //wolfExample.eat(vegFood);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: Add catch code
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So, If you call `wolfExample.eat(vegFood);`  your code will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your Carnivore class and Wolf class is same.

You have not passed name for your 'meatExample'

And try instantiating Meat object and assign it in Food class

```
Food meatExample = new Meat("Beef");
```

This way you are calling getName() method of Food class rather than from Meat class.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your `Food` and `Meat` class design is incorrect, which needs to be fixed as shown below i.e., `Meat` class should take the argument of food `name` property.

**Food class:**

```
public abstract class Food {

    //field that stores the name of the food
    protected String name; 

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

**Meat class:**

```
public class Meat extends Food {

    public Meat(String name) {
        super.name = name;
    }

    //other methods or add other specific meat fields
}
```

**main() method:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create the Meat Object by sending the name in constructor
        Meat meatExample = new Meat("Chicken");
        //other code
}
```

Comment: I think should work apart form the fact that it is looking for a Food variable and a String variable has been passed so I am getting the error message `String cannot be converted to Food`?